# GitHub Workflow on tags not started with semantic release

Tags: github, tags, workflow, github-actions, semantic-release

I have a workflow that should run whenever a new tag is pushed to GitHub:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
```

I use the semantic release plugin to automatically create new versions (`xx.yy.zz`) whenever something is merged into the master. This automatically creates new tags and releases on GitHub.
However, the workflow for new tags is not executed for these new tags. But when I create a new tag manually using `git tag test-tag` and pushing it `git push --tags` the workflow is executed.
Both the semantic release and the manually created tags I can see in GitHub in the `tags` section.

What is the difference between these two approaches, that my workflow is being executed for manual pushes but not for pushes by semantic release?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub recently introduced [changes](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/), that will make workflows not trigger if `[skip ci]` is part of the commit message. Semantic release creates a commit message with `[skip ci]` per default and therefore the workflow was not executed.
I solved my problem by creating a custom semantic release commit message.

Answer (score 0):

FYI what worked for me was to use a Github personal access token as the `GITHUB_TOKEN` as well as [this line](https://github.com/semantic-release/github/issues/264#issuecomment-888398641).